# PYTHON - How to show password when user clicked a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a password entry widget with show parameter and I have created a Check box to show the password which user typed in entry widget . How I can do that
I want to show the password when the user clicked the check box list

Comment: post the code you have

Comment: This is _too broad_ of a question. Please try to narrow down exactly where you're stuck, trying what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example that toggles entry content character substitution. I can only *guess* this is what you want though:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def toggle_password():
    global entry, checkbutton
    if checkbutton.var.get():
        entry['show'] = "*"
    else:
        entry['show'] = ""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    entry.default_show_val = entry['show']
    entry['show'] = "*"
    checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(root,
                                        text="Hide password",
                                        onvalue=True,
                                        offvalue=False,
                                        command=toggle_password)
    checkbutton.var = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
    checkbutton['variable'] = checkbutton.var
    entry.pack()
    checkbutton.pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
def toggle():
    if show_pass.get() == 1:
        entry.config(show= '')
    else:
        entry.config(show= '*')
root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(root, show='*')
show_pass = tk.IntVar()
checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='show password', variable=show_pass, command=toggle)
entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
checkbutton.grid(row=1, column=2)
root.mainloop()
```